# How would I get all the members from a server using discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've been trying to get all the members from a server and list them into the console.
It's been about an hour of me searching around and tweaking code, but I just can't seem to
get it to work.

Here is my  code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

exports.run =  async (bot,message,args) => {
    const list = bot.guilds.cache.get(server);

    list.members.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username));

    if (member) {
        for (user of list.members) {
            console.log(user[1].username);
        }
    }
}   

exports.help = {
    name: 'memberlog'
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `server` is not defined in the code you provided. Also, have you enabled the privileged intent for receiving guild member info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to fetch all the server members from the API, then log them.

```js
const list = bot.guilds.cache.get('serverId')
const members = await list.members.fetch();
members.each((member) => {
    console.log(member.user.username);
})
```

Comment: Sorry for bad indentation, it’s hard on mobile, and I’m still trying to learn...

Comment: Mobile use indentation like hell :3